# How to rewrite my transfer transaction?

Tags: pending-transactions, nonce

So I've made a simple tx to transfer. And it has been broadcasted.

But I did not calculate the gas price properly so the tx is in still pending status.

That seems takes long time.

What if I make same tx and same nonce with more high enough gas price.

Will it rewrite or revert the previous pending TX?
Will the mempool revert my previous tx...

Comment: It should override the previous transaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will overwrite your previous transaction, and due to the higher gas price, hopefully will get mined sooner!

MyEtherWallet provide a tool to do just this, though you'll need your original transaction hash. You can [use it here](https://www.myetherwallet.com/#check-tx-status), and find [instructions here!](https://kb.myetherwallet.com/transactions/check-status-of-ethereum-transaction.html)